# Wrapping method in a macro in C++

Tags: c++, debugging, error-handling, macros

In my framework I want to know line number, file path and method name *of a caller client's code*. So, for example, the framework has a method B(), a client uses the framework and calls `B()` at line X, file path Y. For me to do some error reporting I want to know X and Y.

Obvious solution to this would be to wrap `B()` in a macro:

`#define B() B(__LINE__, __FILE__, ...)` so that the client wouldn't have to specify __LINE__ and __FILE__ macros.

Is this a good design choice, if not, how to do it the good way?

Comment: This isn't uncommon at all, especially for reporting log information relevant to source code location.

Comment: @WhozCraig well then what is common?

Comment: Perhaps the specific negation threw you off? "isn't uncommon" = is NOT uncommon = is common.  In other words, What you're doing is commonly done.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach may be fine, but you might want to consider an alternative if you have to make a lot of such methods:

```
struct Location {
   const char *file;
   int line;
};

#define LOC (Location{__FILE__,__LINE__})

struct Framework {
   void B(const Location &);
};
```

// Client code

```
Framework f;
f.B(LOC);
```

If you have a lot of methods like B, this reduces the number of macros that need to be written in exchange for making the client code a little more tedious.  You'll have to weigh the trade-offs.

Comment: This approach is better because you need only one macro for everything. You can choose a name for it to minimize the chance to interfere with anything.